# How to Zoom camera using pan gesture like TikTok App

Tags: ios, swift, zooming, gesture, pan

I am working on video recorder app and I want feature as Titok for example on pan gesture they are zooming the camera I have used following code but using this code I can zoom with drag that is not feasible I want continues zoom In and Zoom out.

```
@objc func previewPan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        viewShoot.isHidden = false
        //DispatchQueue.main.async {


        if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {

            //self.StartRecording()

            //self.startPoint = recognizer.location(in: self.viewShoot)
            startPoint = recognizer.location(in: self.viewAnimate)

            self.zoomAtStart = self.recorder.videoZoomFactor

        } else if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.changed {

            //let newPoint = recognizer.location(in: self.viewShoot)
            let newPoint = recognizer.location(in: self.viewAnimate)

            let scale = self.startPoint.y / newPoint.y
            var newZoom = scale * self.zoomAtStart

            if newZoom > self.maxZoomFactor {
                newZoom = self.maxZoomFactor
            } else if newZoom < self.minZoomFactor {
                newZoom = self.minZoomFactor
            }
            self.recorder.videoZoomFactor = newZoom

            //------->
            //self.viewShoot.isHidden = false
            //self.viewAnimate.isHidden = false

            //self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.viewShoot)
            self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.viewAnimate)

            let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)

            //self.viewShoot.center = CGPoint(x: self.viewShoot.center.x + translation.x, y: self.viewShoot.center.y + translation.y)
            self.viewAnimate.center = CGPoint(x: self.viewAnimate.center.x + translation.x, y: self.viewAnimate.center.y + translation.y)


            recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)

        } else if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended {

            //self.StopRecording()

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.250) {
                //self.viewShoot.frame = self.originalPossion
                self.viewAnimate.frame = self.originalPossion
            }
        }
        //}
    }
```

Please help.!

Comment: I think you are mixing two gestures up. Isn't the `UIPinchGesture` what you are looking for? Take a look at: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipinchgesturerecognizer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this by using [NextLevelZoom](https://github.com/NextLevel/NextLevel)